# conditional variance (check the solution)

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

$ f_{x,y}(x,y) = c \\  0\le x \le 25 \\   {x^2 \over 25} \le y $

Find Var$[X|Y=16]$

So here is how I proceeded:-

Var$[X|Y=16] = E[{X^2}|Y=16]-(E[X|Y=16])^2 \\
E[X|Y=16] = \int_{0}^{20}xf_x(X|Y=16) \\
Now, f_x(x|y=16)= \frac{f_{x,y}(x,y)}{f_y(Y=16)}\\
\\f_y(Y=y)=\int_{0}^{5\sqrt[]{y}}\, c\, \ dx\\
\\\Rightarrow f_y(Y=16)=20c\\
\\\therefore f_x(x|y=16)= \frac{f_{x,y}(x,y)}{f_y(Y=16)} = \frac{c}{20c} = {1\over20}\\
E[X|Y=16] = \int_{0}^{20}xf_x(X|Y=16) = \int_{0}^{20}x\frac{1}{20}\,\ dx = 10
 \\
Similarly,\\ E[X^2|Y=16] = \int_{0}^{20}x^2f_x(X|Y=16) = \int_{0}^{20}x^2\frac{1}{20}\,\ dx= {400\over3}\\
\therefore , Var[X|Y=16] = E[{X^2}|Y=16]-(E[X|Y=16])^2= {400\over3} -100 ={100\over3} $

Is my answer correct ? I am not quite so sure about limits on the integration.
Any kind of help shall be appreciated

Comment: why is the upper limit 20 and not 25? Is there a rationale that you put 20 for x

Comment: When y=16 , x =$(25*16)^{1/2}$ = 20

Comment: Take a look at this example, and follow the procedure, you have to find the marginal distribution of Y first, and then find the conditional distribution of X/Y=y and then find the expected value and variance. https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/117

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f_{X,Y}(x,16)$ is constant on $[0,20]$ and takes value $0$ for $x\notin[0,20]$.

This information tells us that $X$ under condition $Y=16$ has uniform distribution over $[0,20]$.

So it has the same distribution as $10+10U$ where $U$ has [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) over $[-1,1]$.

Observe that here $\mathbb EU=0$ by symmetry so that $\text{Var}(U)=\mathbb EU^2=\frac12\int^{1}_{-1}u^2du=\int^{1}_{-1}u^2du=\frac13$.

Then we find: $$\text{Var}(X\mid Y=16)=\text{Var}(10+10U)=100\text{Var}(U)=100\mathbb EU^2=\frac{100}3$$

This agrees with your answer and illustrates that things can be done more easily.

Comment: thank you. I cannot follow when you state that 20+10U has the same distribution as Uni [0,20]. Since $E[20+10U] =20 +10*0 =20$ ,while Uni[0,20] has an expected value of 10.

Comment: I made a typo there, sorry. I should be $10+10U$ instead. Repaired now.